# Is there a desktop client for Tumblr?

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm a heavy user of Tumblr. Is there an Ubuntu desktop client that would let me see Tumblr posts from my dashboard and tag which ones I'm following?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two clients that I know of; Grumblr and OpenTumblr. I don't think you can follow people from within them, but they work for just about everything related to posting.

If you want the full features of Tumblr, you can even create a desktop application from within Chromium or using Mozilla's Chromeless technology.

Comment: The reason i looking for desktop client is that i wasnt able to keep track of post which are newly posted after my last visit to the webpage. Is there any way to see the unread post?

Comment: @Learner: only with a web app.